# Get family relationships from Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

How can I query a data on my friend's family relationships on Facebook (assuming they are visible to me normally)? Getting something like a JSON object as the response would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Family appears to be accessible as an array under the User class via FQL.
[See documentation here](http://yourpalmark.github.com/facebook-actionscript-api/docs/com/facebook/graph/data/fql/user/FQLUser.html)

Answer (score 1):

Via graph API it will be:

https://graph.facebook.com/UID/family

which requires user_relationships/friends_relationships extended permissions

OR FQL

SELECT profile_id, relationship FROM family WHERE profile_id =